# Linux mail server and Outlook configuration

Tags: linux, email, microsoft-outlook, fedora, sendmail

I have a linux box where I am  hosting my own internal `mail server`using `sendmail`. I used to send mails to a `abc` user in the mail server from my windows outlook using `abc@mail` keyword in the `To` field in outlook, `mail` is mapped in host file to the lnux/mail server IP address. But now I am trying to configure the same in a different windows machine and I get the error `Microsoft Outlook does not recognize 'abc@mail'`. But if I try the `server IP address`, then it works.

> abc@server ip address ----- works
>
> abc@mail ----- doesn't work

Not sure what I am missing, any tips?

On further research, I found out if I type in `abc@mail.domain` then it works.
So could it be some mapping missing in the domain controller?

Comment: Did you add the domain name in the /etc/hosts ?